# How can I create profiles in the AWS CloudShell to access different roles?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, aws-cloudshell

The new *CloudShell* service from AWS allows me to get a CLI session directly within the browser.
In this session, I am acting under my currently active role:

```
$ aws sts get-caller-identity
{
    "UserId": "AROA2MDGRZUIRD434HHAF:johndoe",
    "Account": "123456789012",
    "Arn": "arn:aws:sts::123456789012:assumed-role/myrole/johndoe"
}
```

I can assume another role from `myrole` as expected:

```
$ aws sts assume-role --role-arn arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/otherRole --role-session-name mySession123
{
    "Credentials": {
        "AccessKeyId": "ASIA...",
        "SecretAccessKey": "...",
        "SessionToken": "...",
        "Expiration": "2021-04-28T16:29:55+00:00"
    },
    "AssumedRoleUser": {
        "AssumedRoleId": "AROA...:mySession123",
        "Arn": "arn:aws:sts::123456789012:assumed-role/otherRole/mySession123"
    }
}
```

Now I want to configure a CLI profile to use `otherRole`. I tried an entry like this:

```
[profile otherRole]
role_arn = arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/otherRole
```

but this causes an error, because I have to specify either a `credential_source` or a `source_profile`.

From an EC2 instance with a service role I would set `credential_source=Ec2InstanceMetadata` but this doesn't work here.
Setting `source_profile` to `default` also causes an error:

```
The source profile "default" must have credentials.
```

How can I create a CLI-profile within the AWS CloudShell to persistentely assume another role?

Comment: Looks like you may have to persist the credentials associated with your CloudShell identity to the default profile in `~/.aws/config` in order to be able to do this because credential_source doesn't appear to support this use case.

Comment: But what if I do not even have long-term credentials for my current identity (like using a role in a different account)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer to be documented [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/credref/latest/refdocs/setting-global-credential_source.html).
*CloudShell* ist not using EC2 instances but is rather running in an ECS based container. Thus setting the `credential_source` to `EcsContainer` does the trick:

```
[profile otherRole]
credential_source=EcsContainer
role_arn=arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/otherRole
```